# PyImport_Import failing when submodules are imported in a python module

Tags: python, c++, python-c-api, python-embedding

I have a cpp code like this:

```cpp
void callPython() {
    Py_Initialize();    
    PyObject* sysPath = PySys_GetObject("path");
    PyList_Append(sysPath, PyUnicode_FromString("/jarvis_repo/src/cpp/packages/jarvis/nlp/"));
    // Load the module
    PyObject *pName = PyUnicode_FromString("my_mod");
    PyObject *pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);
    if (pModule != NULL) {
        std::cout << "Python module found\n";       

        PyObject* pFunc = PyObject_GetAttrString(pModule, "my_func");
        if(pFunc != NULL){
            PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, NULL);
        } else {
            std::cout << "Couldn't find func\n";
        }
    }
    else {
        PyErr_Print();
        std::cout << "Python Module not found\n";
}     
    Py_Finalize();
}
```

I also have two files my_mod.py and test.py in the same directory `/jarvis_repo/src/cpp/packages/jarvis/nlp/` as follows:

**`my_mod.py`**

```py
from test import coreDM
def my_func():
    print("my_func() got called")
    coreDM()
```

**`test.py`**

```py
class coreDM():
    def __init__(self):
        print("Initialized test")

    def print_message():
        print("Hello from coreDM")
```

When `from test import coreDM` and `coreDM()` is omitted from `my_mod.py`,
**PyImport_Import works fine and prints `my_func() got called` else it returns NULL.** Any ideas why this might be happening?
Thanks in advance!

ERROR Message:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'coreDM'
Python Module not found
```

Comment: Have you tried displaying the exception message? `NULL` indicates an error, the message may tell you what is wrong. Odds are something is wrong with `coreDM` that's raising an exception on import (usually a `SyntaxError` or a recursive dependency on `dmEngine`), but without a [MCVE], we can't say much beyond that.

Comment: Added minimal reproducible example. BTW how to display the exception message from `PyImport_Import`?

Comment: I figured out how to print the error message. I used `PyErr_Print();`. Updated question with the error message received.

Comment: `test` is always a dublious name for a module because the CPython testsuite is called `test`.

Comment: Tried changing test.py to some other name. Still didn't work.

Comment: `from .modulename import coreDM`? Note the extra dot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `PyList_Insert` in place of `PyList_Append` to get test imported from the location you want.

as @DavidW mentioned there is an importable module in the core libs called `test`.

change

```
PyList_Append(sysPath, PyUnicode_FromString("/jarvis_repo/src/cpp/packages/jarvis/nlp/"));
```

to

```
PyList_Insert(sysPath, 0, PyUnicode_FromString("/jarvis_repo/src/cpp/packages/jarvis/nlp/"));
```

so the `test` module is first found in **/jarvis_repo/src/cpp/packages/jarvis/nlp/** and not in core libs.

**Note:** you should rename `test` instead